# Generate CSV from JSON in Swift use DataFrame

Tags: swift

I am working towards trying to feed in data from an external API into an AI/ML model that I am working on in swift. For this, I want to be able to train the model based on a CSV input. So, I am trying to use a DataFrame in swift to convert the JSON to a CSV.

Keep reading for more clarity, but the TL;DR is:
What is the correct way to convert JSON to a CSV file where items in the JSON can be in an array with more than one value imbedded?

I first start by getting the movies and encoding that with a JSONEncoder(), from there I pass that JSON data into the Swift API DataFrame, to create a DataFrame from it. Then I use the built in method writeCSV to write the data frame to a CSV.

While it does successfully write to the CSV, the data does not look exactly as I would think it would. Looking at the JSON model directly, I believe this is because for some elements in the json, they return as an arrays with with different options. In the JSON below, an example of this is with the director of the movie.

Here is the method I wrote to do the write of the CSV.
I convert the model to json data, and then use the .writeCSV from DataFrame to write the CSV.

```
public func createCSV(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) async {

        // Fetches stored movies from CoreData and converts them to local version of model
        let movies = await fetchMovies(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate)

        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(movies) {
            if let json = String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8) {

                do {

                    // Create the DataFrame from .json data
                    let dataFrame = try DataFrame(jsonData: encoded)

                    writeDataframeToCsv(dataFrame: dataFrame)
                } catch {
                    Swift.debugPrint("Unable to create DataFrame: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }


private func writeDataframeToCsv(dataFrame: DataFrame, csvName: String = "MyCsv", fileExtension: String = "csv") {
        let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: csvName, relativeTo: directoryURL).appendingPathExtension(fileExtension)

        do {
            try dataFrame.writeCSV(to: fileURL, options: .init())
            print(fileURL)
        } catch {
            Swift.debugPrint("Unable to create CSV From DataFrame: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

And here is an example of the JSON.

```
{
    "Title": "Avengers: Endgame",
    "Year": "2019",
    "Rated": "N/A",
    "Released": "26 Apr 2019",
    "Runtime": "N/A",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Fantasy, Sci-Fi",
    "Director": [
        "Anthony Russo",
        "Joe Russo"
    ],
    "Writer": "Christopher Markus, Stephen McFeely, Stan Lee (based on the Marvel comics by), Jack Kirby (based on the Marvel comics by), Jim Starlin (comic book)",
    "Actors": "Bradley Cooper, Brie Larson, Chris Hemsworth, Chris Evans",
    "Plot": "After the devastating events of Avengers: Infinity War (2018), the universe is in ruins. With the help of remaining allies, the Avengers assemble once more in order to undo Thanos' actions and restore order to the universe.",
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Awards": "N/A",
    "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNGZiMzBkZjMtNjE3Mi00MWNlLWIyYjItYTk3MjY0Yjg5ODZkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDg4NjY5OTQ@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Ratings": [
        "Good",
        "Great"
    ],
    "Metascore": "N/A",
    "imdbRating": "N/A",
    "imdbVotes": "N/A",
    "imdbID": "tt4154796",
    "Type": "movie",
    "DVD": "N/A",
    "BoxOffice": "N/A",
    "Production": "Marvel Studios",
    "Website": "N/A",
    "Response": "True"
}
```

When I inspect the CSV file, for the Director column I see the following in the cell:

```
[Optional({
    Director =     (
        "Anthony Russo,
    );

}),
Optional({
    Director =     (
      Joe Russo"
    );
})]
```

What is the correct way to convert JSON to a CSV where an entity in the JSON can have multiple values/options?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. I don't know if it's the JSON parsing, or the CSV that is your issue. I see nowhere a method that iterate over each property in some order and add comma (or any other separator) between the values. It'd be nice to show expected output (as your question is unclear).

Comment: @Larme Look in the OP's `writeDataframeToCsv` function. It calls `writeCSV` on a `DataFrame` instance.

Comment: what is `DataFrame`?  How would you expect the output to be rendered in a CSV?  Do you want the array to be converted to multiple rows with the other columns the same?  Or should the array be converted into some sort of quoted string? (e.g. `"value1,value2,value3"`). CSV doesn't have a simple/defined way of handling repeated content.

Comment: @Paulw11 Have a look at Apple's documentation: [`DataFrame`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tabulardata/dataframe).

Comment: Thanks @HangarRash - I hadn't seen that before.

Comment: Thanks @HangarRash Totally forgot that DataFrame is an Apple Class for that conversion.

Comment: Could you clarify your JSON as it's unclear? Rating is wrong and is Director an array with only one value (with two separated one), or two values? And what is `tracks`?

Comment: JSON was cleaned with an online validator